# Adding item to session on click

Tags: jquery, laravel

Using Laravel, in the following scenario, how can I add the book id to the session?

```
@foreach( $books as $book )
    <li>
        {{ $book->name }}
        <a href="#" onClick='addBookToList( "<?= $book->id ?>" )'>Add Book To List</a>
    </li>
@endforeach
```

Here's my attempt. I know that it is not supposed to work this way, but how do I need to change it?

```
<script>
function addBookToList( bookId )
{
    <? Session::put( 'bookId', bookId ); ?>
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Alexander is spot on. I'll use a route to process the request, but you can use the exact same code in a controller.

```
//routes.php
Route::post('/ajax/add-book', function(){
     Session::put( 'bookId', Input::get('bookId') );
});
```

Your html/js implementation is good. Here's another way to achieve the same thing:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-book="<?= $book->id ?>">Add Book To List</a>
```

And in your js file

```
$('a[data-book]').click(function($e){
    $e.preventDefault();
     $.post("/ajax/add-book", {
        "bookId": $(this).data('book')
      });
});
```

Comment: I agree with your answer, though you could also have added the implementation of a book array in the session. The session item would be `books`, and you would extract the contents of that first, then add the book, then put the array back into the session item.

Comment: Thanks, this really helped! How would you suggest implementing the array version?

Answer (score 0):

Never used Laravel but I believe something along these lines might work:

```
var addBookToList = function(bookId){
  $.post("session.php", {
    "bookId": bookId
  });
};
```

```
<a href="#" onClick='addBookToList( "<?= $book->id ?>" )'>Add Book To List</a>
```

```
<?php Session::put( 'bookId', Input::get('bookId') ); ?>
```